# XFX 6770 with 3 monitors

Tags: graphics-card

I bought and installed the XFX6770.  It has 4 connections, 1 DP, 1 HDMI, and 2 DVI.
http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=869628&CatId=7005

I can only get 2 monitors to work at a time.  I have both DVI ports used and currently using a  DP to HDMI adapter for the 3rd.  Only the DP 1 DVI will work at a time.  in the screen resolution screen in windows, all 3 monitors are detected, but one is always disabled.  When I try to enable the 3rd, I get an error messagebox stating that it cannot apply display settings.  I get the same problem when use the HDMI port with 2 DVI.  The front of the box clearly states support for up to 3 monitors.

My question is this:  How in the world do I get the 3rd monitor to work?  I have Catalyst installed, but it only picks up 2 monitors as well.  Is this a software problem?  A driver?  Maybe I missed a power connector on the card?  I connected one from my power supply to the card already.  Maybe I have to use the connectors in a certain combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an active DP to HDMI adapter. 
Most adapters that are sold are passive. The active adapters are usually a bit more expensive. Doublecheck that your adapter is active, and if not; buy one.